# git checkout modifies too many files

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-post-receive

I'm using git to publish a web site.
The workflow is roughly:

```
$ git add my_file
$ git commit -m comment my_file
$ git push # Just house-keeping, goes to my master repo
$ git push ssh://user@webserver//var/www/repo.git
```

A post-receive hook on the web server looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

working=$(pwd)
working=${working##*/}
working=../${working%.*}
while read oldrev newrev ref ; do
    branch=$(echo ${ref} | cut -d/ -f3)
    GIT_WORK_TREE=${working} git checkout -f ${branch}
done
```

The vast majority of the time this works just fine.
When I say fine I mean, if I've added one file, the checkout modifies that one file.

Only if I wait for a day and then make another commit & push, the git checkout in the post-receive hook re-fetches every single file in my working copy. Not only does it take ages, but it then messes with an rsync I run later on.

what can be happening overnight so that the checkout that happens tomorrow is wildly different from one that I can repeat over and over again today?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using branches at all?  It looks like, from your post-receive hook, that your not filtering on which ref you want to use to host your site's code.  Instead, it does a checkout for every modified ref.  If you push some code to another branch, then your site will be updated to reflect that.  I think you probably only want to run the checkout for the ref that matters (perhaps `refs/heads/master`), and that's it.

Perhaps changing

```
while read oldrev newrev ref ; do
    branch=$(echo ${ref} | cut -d/ -f3)
    GIT_WORK_TREE=${working} git checkout -f ${branch}
done
```

to

```
while read oldrev newrev ref ; do
    if [ "$ref" == "refs/heads/master" ]; then
        branch=$(echo ${ref} | cut -d/ -f3)
        GIT_WORK_TREE=${working} git checkout -f ${branch}
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'm not using branches at all. So I always see git mentioning that I'm already on master. However, to remove the ambiguity, I'll simplify the post-receive hook. The biggest problem is that it works most of the time but fails if I push more than a day since the last push.

Comment: Aside: instead of `cut -d/ -f3`, generally better to strip off `refs/heads/` with `${ref#refs/heads/}`, lest this treat a branch name like `refs/heads/foo/bar` as if it were just `foo` rather than `foo/bar`.  Not a problem in this case, but then, in this case you could just do `branch=master`. :-)

Comment: True.  I was just showing him how to conditionalize the block, if it wasn't obvious.  I prefer to use notation you pointed out myself.  But you're absolutely right, in this case it could be cleaned up to say `branch=master`, or just drop the branch name into the checkout command.